# Why this Regex does not works?

Tags: java, regex

I have method and it accepts a date as a String and my goal is to find out the month Type as it numeric or String like 01.02....or jan, feb so i need to compare this month value to Regex but unfortunately if month field contain numeric value then **match.find()** not works but why? Thanks in Advance

```
public static String detectMonthType(String date) {
    String[] parts = {};

    if(date.contains("/")) {
        parts = date.split("/");
    } else {
        parts = date.split("-");
    }

    String dateType = "";
    String month = parts[1];
    String strPattern = "^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(month);

    if(match.find()) {
        return dateType = "numericMonth";
    } else {
        return dateType = "strMonth";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: my input is like 07/11/16

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: as my input contains numeric month value so i expect here if block should be true but unfortunately it false.

Comment: Works fine for me. By the way, what's the point of `dateType`?

Comment: actually there is no need to declare "dateType" instance i can directly return string if match but it does not works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp isn't going to match a two-digit number if the first digit is zero... just like in your input.  You should probably branch the regex differently as ^(0[1-9]+|1[0-2])$ which, unlike your displayed regex will *exclude* zero and impossible months like 13.

Comment: Thanks It Works Fine

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is wrong. This should work:

```
String strPattern = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])*$";
```

`"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"` expands to `"^0$"` and `"^[1-9][0-9]*$"`, so it will match a single "0", but not anything start with "0".

Comment: That pattern will match 13, which is an invalid month.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Yes, you are right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for numeric month you can use following regx

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])$
```

Below regex pattern will check single or double digit moth for example 1 or 01 is valid month Jan

```
^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])$
```

Below pattern for string months:

```
(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)
```

And more generic which checks short or full moth name is

```
(Jan(uary)?|(Feb)ruary?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)
```

This can be used as

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```